# WPF OneWayToSource binding

Tags: wpf, binding, binding-mode

In a OneWayToSource binding is there anyway i can specify, in xaml, the path to use at the target. This is possible for the source. Is my only choice to write a converter?

Regards

Comment: The the target is where you put the binding. i.e. if you want to update from a TextBox to a property you put the binding on the TextBox.Text. Or am I misunderstanding you? Can you give an example?

Comment: @fsl: Add some code please. Is your source a non-element(a class not derived from UIElement)? If yes you can use DataContext.

Answer (score 3):

Well the source is the Path you set for your Binding :

```
Text="{Binding Path=Customer, Mode=OneWayToSource}"
```

You don't need to write a Converter.

Answer (score 0):

In the example above:

```
Text = Target
Customer = Source
```

You just need to add the `Mode=OneWayToSource` on any binding, you do not need anything else.

Can you explain more?